# ormlite, allow a single record in a table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm wondering whether there's a way to force a table to have only one record. My use case is that I only allow one user to log into the app at a time, and overwrite that only record (if there's one). 
I know it defeats the point of having a database if only 1 item is allowed. But I've got other tables with normal behaviour (multiple rows), only the `logged-in-user table` needs this, and I don't want to use another persisting scheme just for this case.

Any tip how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: `I know it defeats the point of having a database if only 1 item is allowed.` it does. Why not store the user somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering whether there's a way to force a table to have only one record.

There is no way from a *database* perspective or via ORMLite but there are many ways that you can implement this in your own code.

One way that comes to mind is to have a `LoggedIn` table with a single row in it.  You then can do some sort of conditional update of the row in the table.

Something like (in pseudo code):

```
use the UpdateBuilder to make a conditional update:
    like: UPDATE LoggedIn SET user = my-user-name WHERE user IS NULL
refresh the logged-in entity
if my-user-name.equals(loggedIn.getUser()) then
    I'm logged in and can continue
else
    I can't login because someone beat me to it.
```

One of the tricks of this method is that you need to set the user back to null later when the user is logged out.  If the application crashes then you will somehow need to reset.  Maybe some sort of login timeout?  You mention Android so maybe you could clear the logged-in table when you start unless this is a remote database.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.